# What are the limitations of Reflection.Emit vs. other assembly generation techniques?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, code-generation, reflection.emit

I've used Reflection.Emit in the past to write a compiler, but I know the standard compilers don't use it, and in [an answer to another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598958/writing-a-compiler-for-net-il-or-bytecode) I saw a mention that there are some things Reflection.Emit is unable to do.

What are the limitations of Reflection.Emit that I should be aware of if I plan on writing another compiler for .NET?

Comment: What language are you trying to compile? Emit will support most things you will want to do, although maybe not elegantly.

Comment: Beware that not all .NET-y platforms support Reflection.Emit - for instance, the Compact Framework.

Comment: @Gabe, I don't have a language in mind yet, just looking for general information.