# Generating IL for .Net Platform

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, il

I’m writing a small compiler in C# and planning to generate IL instructions for .Net platform using `System.Reflection.Emit`. My question is, it is advisable to use `System.Reflection.Emit` for generating IL for production compilers.

If it is not advisable to use `System.Reflection.Emit` for generating IL for production compilers, do we have alternative libraries/tools for that purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.Reflection.Emit` is fine for production compilers, though you may want to take a look at [mono-cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

Comment: +1.  Microsoft.CCI is also an option.  It seems like performance is a strong consideration in that library (explicit name tables being one example), so it might allow you to make a faster compiler.  But in my limited use, I much preferred Cecil's API.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog article describing some problems with `Reflection.Emit` that probably aren't serious limitations for your project but you can be the judge:

- [The limitations of Reflection.Emit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2009/11/29/the-limitations-of-reflection-emit.aspx)

If those issues don't bother you, then you can use this SO question for tips on the generation using `Reflection.Emit` and writing the assembly to disk:

- [Writing a Compiler for .net - IL or Bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598958/writing-a-compiler-for-net-il-or-bytecode)

Answer (score 2):

While `System.Reflection.Emit` let's you do code gen it's the oldest of the code gen APIs in the .NET framework and it requires understanding of IL. The expression trees introduced in .NET 3.5 and extended in .NET 4.0 (can't create new types) but they can be used to assemble complete method bodies.

Answer (score 1):

`Reflection.Emit` is *generally* fine, but  `IKVM.Reflection.Emit` (available from Mono) may have more options if the assembly you are generating is not for the same platform (i.e. you want to build a silverlight dll from your compiler, which is written in "full" .NET).

Comment: mono is awesome in every way. They build lots of cool stuff everybody .NET developer should be aware of. I did not know about `IKVM`.